# Pressing enter produces ^M instead of a newline

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

For example, if I am `tail -f`ing a file or `read`ing user input, `<Enter>` will produce `^M` in the terminal instead of ending the `read` or adding a newline to stdout. `^J` works fine.

I'm `ssh`ing into the ubuntu system, if that matters. This happens to me both in zsh and bash. One solution I played with is remapping the `^M` to `^J` in zsh, but that seems like it wouldn't fix the root problem. Anyone know what might be causing this?

Edit: To answer some questions, I'm `ssh`ing into Ubuntu from OSX. I'm using iTerm and zsh. I also forgot to mention that I'm using tmux on the Ubuntu machine.

Edit 2: Missed a question. When I type `Ctrl-V Enter` I get `^M` (both on OSX and Ubuntu).

Edit 3: On OSX and Ubuntu `echo $TERM` produces `screen-256color`.

Comment: What are you Using to ssh to Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes --- and from which OS? It seems a TERM problem.

Comment: What do you get if you type **Ctrl** + **V** followed by **Enter**? As you are able to execute commands just fine, this is definitely not a problem of the shell.

Comment: An (involuntary) restart of my OSX box seems to have fixed the issue... I guess it's one of those. Hopefully it's gone for good.

Comment: Also for me the only thing that worked was a restart including the clearance of the NVRAM. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound to also reset the NVRAM of OSx

Answer (score 369):

In case anybody else has this problem, it is most likely a problem with the stty terminal line setting rather than a TERM problem. If this happens to you again, try running `stty sane` and let us know if that fixes it.

Comment: This works on OS X as well.

Comment: Worked for me (Mint 17.1).

Comment: Work on Ubuntu Bionic

Comment: works well on iTerm2 on Mojave

Comment: worked for my on kitty on archlinux

Comment: worked for me on (Ubuntu 16.04, Alacritty, tmux)

Comment: Worked on macOS Catalina ZSH. Question: Why does this only happen sometimes? And does `stty sane` fix it permanently or will I need to re-run this when/if it happens again? Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaPinter: it is a temporary fix since it is caused by programs that do not clean up properly when they exit.

Comment: The secret of how you RUN `stty sane` when you cannot press enter would be useful here. `^J`?

Comment: in `debian10` is not working !!

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 20.04 as well (remotely, in a browser window - a dockerized Jupyter Notebook's terminal tab)

Comment: @danmackinlay I had to `CTRL` + `C` to quit my bash script and get back to the terminal and then run `stty sane` there. That worked for me. Not sure if you can't even press enter from the base terminal or not.

Comment: This worked perfectly in Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 56):

Try running `stty -a` to view your terminal settings. My suspicion is that your `icrnl` setting is not set and will be shown as `-icrnl` (the minus sign means that it is turned off) instead of having its usual setting of being on. Here is how my terminal is normally set up when I log in:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 45; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

And I have no problem with line endings: either return (^M) or enter (^J) will end input lines. But if I turn `icrnl` off then ^M codes suddenly appear each time I am talking to a program and hit enter:

```
$ stty -icrnl
$ read line
Line of text^M^M^M^M
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 45; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

The code `icrnl` means “turn carriage returns into newlines” and hides from the running program that you might be typing ^M when Unix really wants ^J. Old keyboards used to have a separate Return and Enter key (where Return typically advanced you through a form and Enter submitted it), but today we generally have only one line-ending key and so this terminal setting helps combine the two meanings.

Add the `stty icrnl` command to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` if you find that this is indeed the problem setting.

Comment: I think I turned off `ircnl` by accidental key-smashing working in a live terminal session. Just ran `$ stty icrnl` and it fixed itself.

Comment: Not sure where to put it, but it did work.  Host machine or the one I'm ssh'ed into?  Too late now, already fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this problem with zsh on Ubuntu 20.04 and neither `tty sane` nor `stty icrnl` worked.

As it turns out it was caused by disabling <kbd>NumLock</kbd>.
Once I re-enabled it the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key behaved normally again.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

CTRL+Enter is gonna solve your problem. Whenever you want to run a command on the commend line you can press CTRL+ENTER.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1234620)