# Ubuntu Minecraft Server Terminal Displaying Odd Characters

Tags: command-line, server, vim, minecraft

When players chat on my Ubuntu Minecraft server they can see the chat clearly in the game and it's fine. However when I look at the terminal all I see is 1 bracket for each time they enter something in as shown in the picture shown:
[picture of chat in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSAoH.png)

When I also look at my latest.log file using vim the chat shows up but with odd characters here: [latest.log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z0wf.png)

With some of the minecraft commands it also displays weird characters as shown:

```
[23:33:29] [Server thread/INFO]: [PermissionsEx] Permissions file successfully reloaded
[23:33:29] [Server thread/INFO]: ^[[0;37;1mPermissions reloaded^[[m
```

I've tried looking at this thread [Pressing enter produces ^M instead of a newline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441744/pressing-enter-produces-m-instead-of-a-newline) and tried to use the command "stty sane" but that didn't help. My stty settings also have icrnl enabled as well.

I've also tried to restart my server but it still shows the same characters.

Comment: They are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). `0;37;1m` means bold white text.

Comment: But what about the player chat, it is hidden by a bracket, can you explain the reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are terminal color codes. The log file doesn't filter those out, and Vim shows them explicitly instead of changing colors on you.

Comment: But what about the player chat, it is hidden by a bracket, can you explain the reasoning behind that or have some sort of solution to that? And is there anyway where I can just have vim make the color codes just show the color?

Comment: You can use `cat` instead of `vim`. Vim is an editor; if you couldn't edit escape sequences, that would be a problem. I don't know what happens to be logging `[` or why.