# pressing enter in vim command mode produces M

Tags: command-line, xubuntu

I have a similar issue like that one discussed here:
[Pressing enter produces ^M instead of a newline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441744/pressing-enter-produces-m-instead-of-a-newline#comment925104_441744)

The advice to type

> stty sane

didn't fix the issue.

In vim I can't write a file due to the misinterpretation of enter.

If I type CTRL-V and enter in terminal it produces: ^[OM

```
$ stty --all

speed 38400 baud; rows 23; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

UPDATE even though `stty --all` shows that icrnl is activated typing

```
stty icrnl
```

helps in terminal but not within tmux. The issue still persists in tmux.